# Block Booking Hotel Rooms problem

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem:

A travel company books blocks of rooms are different resorts at a huge discount which it then provides to its clients at a markup.

Resort A has 6 suites, 3 deluxe rooms, 9 standard rooms, and 3 economy rooms in each block

Resort B has 6 suites, 4 deluxe, 6 standard, and 4 economy rooms in each.

Resort C has 7 suites, 4 deluxe, 9 standard, and 4 economy rooms in each.

Resort D has 7 suites, 5 deluxe, 4 standard, and 3 economy rooms in each.

If customers need 155 suites, 95 deluxe rooms, 170 standard rooms, and 85 economy rooms, how many blocks from each hotel should the travel company book so that every room is occupied. Is this possible? If so, determine how many ways there are to do it.

This is for a linear algebra class, and we're supposed to use the matrix form of systems of equations to solve it (rref, linear combinations etc).

I tried using $Ax = b$ where $A$ is the matrix representing the number of rooms of each type in each block from each resort, $x$ is the variable number of blocks to book from each resort, and b is the desired number of rooms of each type (155 suites, 95 deluxe rooms, 170 standard rooms, and 85 economy rooms). But I can't figure out how to conclusively answer the question one way or the other. Is there an $x = (a, b, c, d)$ that yields the exact number of each type of rooms required?

Answer (score 2):

In your matrix, use rows to solve for each type of room, and then columns to designate the resort:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
6 & 6 & 7 & 7\\
3 & 4 & 4 & 5\\
9 & 6 & 9 & 4\\
3 & 4 & 4 & 3
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Then $b$ will be the number you need of each:
$$b=\begin{pmatrix}
155\\95\\170\\85
\end{pmatrix}.$$
The solution 
$$x=\begin{pmatrix}
x_A\\ x_B\\x_C\\x_D
\end{pmatrix}$$
will then denote the number of blocks from each resort you need (or possibly several solutions).

So after you've found all possible solutions, look for integer solutions.  Solve one of these for integer values, e.g. solve $3x_A+4x_B+4x_C+3x_D=85$ for nonnegative integers $x_A,x_B,x_C,x_B$.  This will give an upper bound on the number of integer solutions.  Then plug these back into the solution for the system and see if they fit that form.

Either that, or you'll find some subset of the solution set with $x_A,x_B,x_C,x_D$ being nonnegative.  Look for integer solutions in here.

NOTE:  There may be an easier way to do this last part, but alas I have not studied integer programming.

Comment: So then how do I find the values of the solution space? I feel like this is something I've done before. Using Matlab I determined that A isn't invertible, but that just means there isn't a single solution.

Comment: Not necessarily.  Either no solution exists, or there are infinitely many solutions (I'd put my money on the latter), and presumably on of the infinitely many solutions will have at least one with nonnegative integer values.  Just run Gaussian elimination on this system and see what happens.

Comment: Right, but that gives me a solution that doesn't actually answer the question. I need to know how many solutions there are that only involve integer values for X, Y, Z, and W. You can't book only part of a block that's the whole point.

Comment: Alright now I see what the problem is.  Let me edit.

Comment: I don't suppose there's any way to definitively calculate the exact range. A way to derive an equation or system of equations that describes the integer solution range.

Comment: Not that I am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I did a brute force search up to 20 of each block and $2$ lots of $A$, $4$ of $B$, $12$ of $C$ and $5$ of $D$ works.

Edit:

Everything brute forced and $(6, 7, 6, 5)$ is also a solution.

Comment: What method did you use to find this solution set?

Comment: Tried every possible combination up to 40 of each block. What else?